# Why does my optional one-to-one relationship with Entity Framework Core not work?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an existing sql database with 2 tables that have an optional one-to-one relationship with proper records.

I configured the given relationship with Entity Framework Core for my asp.net core web application as given below:

```cs
// Principal (parent)
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

// Dependent (child)
public class Address
{
    public int? AddressRef { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Person");
    entity.HasKey(k => new { k.Id });
    entity.Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName("PersonRef");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Address>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Address");
    entity.HasKey(x => x.AddressRef);
    entity.Property(e => e.AddressRef).ValueGeneratedNever();

    entity.HasOne(a => a.Person)
            .WithOne(b => b.Address)
            .HasForeignKey<Address>(c => c.AddressRef)
            .IsRequired(false)                  
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull).HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.Address_dbo.Person_AddressRef");
})
```

When I try to add a new Person via DbContext

```cs
var newPerson = new Person()
{
    LastName = model.LastName,
    // ...
};
DbContext.Add(newPerson);
DbContext.SaveChanges()   // Error is thrown
```

I get the ErrorMessage:

> The value of 'Person.Id' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.'

I have tried several variations for configuring the one-to-one relationship but all give the same error.

Any help would gratefully be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your principal entity's Primary Key should be a annotated as AutoGeneratedValue.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
 {
     entity.ToTable("Person");
     entity.HasKey(k => k.Id); // .ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); problem was here
     entity.Property(k => k.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); // <-- Here is the change
     entity.Property(k => k.Id)
           .HasColumnName("PersonRef");
 });
```

Note: `Primiary key` should have a value for `Primary Key` in `Principal Entity` because it will be used as primary key in the `Dependent Entity`

And as @FFad3 tried to tell, in your scenario `Address` is Optional not `Person` as I mentioned above the primary key of the Address should be Mapped from an existing record on `Person` table. You can't have a record of `Address` without having a corresponding person.

You may change it to one-to-many relation to make it possible. in this way in `Person` table you will have a `Foreign Key` for related `Address` (nullable foreign key) and separated `Primary key` on `Address` entity.

If you ask me I will explain you how to do this.

Comment: With entity.HasKey(k => k.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity); I get the red squiggling line -> 'KeyBuilder does not have a definition of HasDatabaseGeneratedOption ....'

Comment: my bad, try `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` instead.

Comment: with ValueGeneratedOnAdd I get the same error

Comment: What is your version of `EFCore` ?

Comment: I have EFCore 6.0.5

Comment: I have updated the answer. please check it.

Comment: I can't recognize the changes that you made in your answer.

Comment: When we use `HasKey()` it returns an object of type `KeyBuilder`. because of that we cant use `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` there. I wrote another line with `.Property(P => P.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd` It works becuase `.Proerty(...)` returns `PropertyBuilder` object. I added more comments on the code.

Comment: Yes, I now understand. I added the property as given in your answer and now everything is working properly! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should change

public virtual Address Address { get; set; } => public virtual Address? Address { get; set; }

also check migration script if Person.Id is set to SqlServer:Identity

Id = table.Column(type: "int", nullable: false)
.Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1")